# poker five card draw with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I Have this code Written with Python. The logic of the Code is to shuffle a deck of Cards, deal one single hand to the player and after Evaluate the Highest rank of the Player's hand and return an appropriate message to the player like. (Ex: Your Hand : 5K 8H 2S 3D 9S
Your Rank : Flush)

I want to use Django framework to create an API that will return an HttpResponse to mimic this (Ex: Your Hand : 5K 8H 2S 3D 9S
Your Rank : Flush) as a Json Object.

I would like to know how would about writing API and which design consideration i should have in mind.

Which part of the code should go into the view to return the appropriate endpoint exemple : the hand of the player the shuffling of the deck, and the rank of the user.

```
from constants import Constant


class Card(Constant):

    def __init__(self, suit, val):
        # initialize the card object
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = val
        # get the rank of the card by indexing the RANKS dictionary
        self.rank = self.RANKS[val]

    def get_rank(self):
        # return the rank of the card
        if self.rank:
            return self.rank
        else:
            raise Exception('No rank')

    def get_suit(self):
        # return the suit of the card
        if self.suit:
            return self.suit
        else:
            raise Exception('No suit')

    def __str__(self):
        # return the string representation of the card
        return f'{self.get_rank()}{self.get_suit()}'

import random
from card import Card


# class to represent a deck of cards


class Deck(Card):

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize the deck object
        self.cards = []
        self.build_deck()

    # Create Our Deck of 52 cards

    def build_deck(self):
        # loop through each suit
        for suit in self.SUITS:
            for rank in self.RANKS:
                self.get_deck().append(Card(suit, rank))
        random.shuffle(self.get_deck())

    # return the deck of cards
    def get_deck(self):
        return self.cards

    # print the deck object as a string
    def __str__(self):
        return " ".join([str(card) for card in self.get_deck()])

    # Shuffle the deck of cards
    def shuffle(self):
        for i in range(len(self.get_deck()) - 1, 0, -1):
            # pick a random index between 0 and i (inclusive)
            if i > 0:
                j = random.randint(0, i)
                # swap the cards at position i and j
                self.get_deck()[i], self.get_deck()[
                    j] = self.get_deck()[j], self.get_deck()[i]
            else:
                # return an empty string if the deck is empty
                raise Exception('No cards to shuffle')
        return True

    # draw a single card from the deck (the bottom card)
    def deal(self):
        if self.get_deck():
            # return the last card in the deck
            return self.get_deck().pop()
        else:
            # return an empty string if the deck is empty
            raise Exception('No cards to deal')
from deck import Deck


# class to represent a hand of cards
class Hand(Deck):

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize the hand object
        self.hand = []

    def get_hand(self):
        # return the hand
        return self.hand

    def __str__(self):
        if self.get_hand():
            # return the string representation of the hand
            return ' '.join([str(card) for card in self.get_hand()])
        else:
            # raise an exception if the hand is empty
            raise Exception('No cards in hand')

    # Make the Hand Iterable
    def __iter__(self):
        if not self.get_hand():
            # raise an exception if the hand is empty
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            # return an iterator for the hand
            return iter(self.get_hand())

    def draw_cards(self, deck, num):
        # draw cards from the deck and add them to the hand
        for _ in range(num):
            # draw a card from the deck
            cards_in_deck = deck.deal()
            if cards_in_deck:
                # add the card to the hand
                self.get_hand().append(cards_in_deck)
            else:
                # raise an exception if the
                raise Exception('No cards to draw')
        # return the string representation of the hand
        return True


class HandRank:

    @staticmethod
    def is_cards_in_sequence(ranks):
        sorted_ranks = sorted(ranks)
        for i in range(len(sorted_ranks) - 1):
            # check if the next card is one rank higher than the current card
            if i == 0:
                # check if the first card is an ace
                if sorted_ranks[i] == 'A' and sorted_ranks[i + 1] == '10':
                    continue
            if sorted_ranks[i] != (sorted_ranks[i + 1] - 1):
                return False
            return True

    # function to return a count of each rank in the hand

    @staticmethod
    def get_counts(ranks):
        ranks = []
        for c in ranks:
            if c in ranks:
                # increment the count of the rank
                ranks[c] += 1
            else:
                # add the rank to the dictionary
                ranks[c] = 1
        return ranks

    # get the rank of the hand
    def get_hand_rank(self, hand):
        suits = [card.suit for card in hand]  # get the suits of the cards
        ranks = [card.rank for card in hand]  # get the ranks of the cards
        # check for Straight flush
        if self.is_cards_in_sequence(ranks) and len(set(suits)) == 1:
            return Constant.STRAIGHT_FLUSH
        # check for four of a kind
        elif self.get_counts(ranks) == 4:
            return Constant.FOUR_OF_A_KIND
        # check for full house
        elif self.get_counts(ranks) == 3 and self.get_counts(ranks) == 2:
            return Constant.FULL_HOUSE
        # check for flush
        elif len(set(suits)) == 1:
            return Constant.FLUSH
        # check for straight
        elif self.is_cards_in_sequence(ranks):
            return Constant.STRAIGHT
        # check for three of a kind
        elif self.get_counts(ranks) == 3:
            return Constant.THREE_OF_A_KIND
        # check for two pair
        elif len(set(self.get_counts(ranks))) == 3:
            return Constant.TWO_PAIR
        # check for one pair
        elif len(set(self.get_counts(ranks))) == 4:
            return Constant.ONE_PAIR
        #
        else:
            return Constant.HIGH_CARD
```

Exemple of the output:

Your Hand : 5K 8H 2S 3D 9S
Your Rank : Flush

Comment: Did you go through the official [django-docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/) on how views, urls work in django. The question scope seems too broad to be answered.

Comment: I did go through the docs but i can't just get how i would go about writing this logic because I'm also thinking about the design element in Vue js.